# Автоматически повторить программу с другими переменными

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Может кто поможет. Можно ли автоматически повторить эту программу 10 раз? Только каждый раз меняя Логин1, Пароль1 на Логин2, Пароль2, в следующий раз Логин2, Пароль2 на Логин3, Пароль3 и так далее. Заранее спасибо!

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from Twitter_auth import Login1, Password1
from Proxy_auth import Log1, Pass1, IP1
import time
import pickle

capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = f"http://{Log1}:{Pass1}@{IP1}"
proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': proxy,
        'https': proxy
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
try:
    driver.page_load_strategy = 'none'
    driver.get(url="https://twitter.com/i/flow/login")
    time.sleep(4)
    login_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "text")
    login_input.send_keys(Login1)
    time.sleep(2)
    login_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(4)
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
    password_input.send_keys(Password1)
    time.sleep(3)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(10)

    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(f"{Login1}_cookies", "wb"))
    time.sleep(5)



except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Составьте кортеж кортежей из пар логин, пароль и пробежитесь по нему циклом:

```
login_password = ((login0,password0), (login1,password1), ...,(loginn,passwordn))
```

```
for login, password in login_password:
    код программы
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!